# Python: How can I print out an object as a regular dictionary without reference?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Object1:
  d = 1

class Object2:
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3
  o = None
```

Where as the o property in Object2 will be a reference of Object1. My final goal is to use **dict** to print out a flat key/pair dict of Object2:

```
b = Object2()
b.a = 2

o = Object1()
o.d = 2

b.o = o

print b.__dict__
```

But I got this:

```
{'a': 2, 'o': <__main__.Object1 instance at 0x2d52290>}
```

Just wonder is there a way I can print out the dic without the reference?

```
{'a': 2, 'o': {'o': 2}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why is 2 the value that should be printed to represent `o`? 2 is its `d` attribute, and if the `d` attribute is what should be printed to represent the whole object, you can define a `__str__()` method for `Object1`.

Comment: The class attributes don't matter here. You're defining them when you define each class but you're dealing with instance attributes when you do for instance `b.a = 2` and `b.__dict__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How a class gets printed is determined by it's `__str__` and `__repr__` methods, so you can add these to `Object1`. Note that you should only do this if you're sure that you want the value of `Object1` to be represented by it's `d` attribute:

```
class Object1:
    d = 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.d)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.d)
```

Output:

```
print b.__dict__
{'a': 2, 'o': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would have to iterate through the dictionary items.

```
for k,v in b.o.items():
    print k,v
```

Or something along those lines.
Also, you can use the pprint [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).